# Es lo mismo un metodo y otro o funciona diferente?

Tags: java, hilos

Si yo tengo

```
hilo1.start();
hilo1.join();
hilo2.start();
hilo2.join();
hilo3.start();
hilo3.join();
```

Ejecuta el hilo1 cuando termine su proceso ejecuta el 2 y luego el 3, mi duda es la siguiete si yo pongo

```
hilo1.start();
hilo2.start();
hilo3.start();
hilo1.join();
hilo2.join();
hilo3.join();
```

Hace lo mismo o ejecuta los 3 hilos y espera a que mueran los 3?osea lanza los 3 hilos simultaneamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es lo mismo: la llamada a `join()` [bloquea el hilo del que llama hasta que el hilo llamado termine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html), por tanto:

- En tu primer ejemplo se lanza el hilo 1 y hasta que no termine no se lanza el hilo 2.
- En el segundo ejemplo se lanzan los tres hilos y luego se espera a que todos terminen.